# localizing my iphone app plist file caused error "could not read data from 'myAppPath/myApp-Info.plist'

Tags: iphone, ios, localization, internationalization, plist

localizing my iphone app plist file caused error "could not read data from 'myAppPath/myApp-Info.plist': The file couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.

That is I highlighted the plist file, and then clicked in the properties to localise it.  It created an English Version.  I then added a French verion.

I see now copies of the plist file in the english and french localisation diretories, however I note it didn't leave a copy in the parent where it was from

Any ideas?  Do I need to duplicate the English version and leave a copy of this in the parent directory?

**PS. Here are the file listing before/after.**

(a) Before Applying Localisation

```
./AppDelegate.h
./AppDelegate.m
./en.lproj
./en.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
./main.m
./test_plist-Info.plist
./test_plist-Prefix.pch
```

(b) After applying (for which there is the error)

```
./AppDelegate.h
./AppDelegate.m
./en.lproj
./en.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
./en.lproj/test_plist-Info.plist
./fr.lproj
./fr.lproj/test_plist-Info.plist
./main.m
./test_plist-Prefix.pch
```

Comment: created a brand new project and tried the same thing & get the same error.  Can change "bundle name" in the plist file and the app name under the icon changes / works.  But when I go to localize the plist file and then run I can the error...

Comment: got the exact same error here. however, not many people seem to have gotten bit by this. Did you solve it in the end?

Answer (score 3):

You don't localize the Info.plist file itself.  Leave the one English version at the root, then create InfoPlist.strings files alongside your internationalized resources in the individual language directories.  It will replace strings at runtime.

For example, if you wanted the German version's app to show up as MeineApp, you'd create an InfoPlist.strings and put it in you de.lproj directory and have it contain:

> "CFBundleDisplayName" = "MeineApp";

Further reading can be found on Apple's site:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009254-102276